# Loop counter returning 0

Tags: python, loops, time-complexity, confusion-matrix, loop-counter

Sorry if this is a bit silly I am new to coding. I tried creating a confusion matrix, I used the unique function and then created a null matrix and tried adding loop counters to be able to determine time-complexity but it returns 0. I think it is because I did not call the function correctly but I do not know how to do it. Thank you so much for your help.

```
L = 0
def confusionmatrix(target, prediction):
    dataframe=creatematrixnull(target)    
    for i in range(len(target)):
        dataframe[target[i]][prediction[i]]+=1
        L=L+1
        
    return dataframe
print(L)
```

Comment: you forgot to ask a question

Comment: If the output is 0 then that's because *len(target) == 0* or if *confusionmatrix()* was never called

Comment: OP isn't actually talking about the return value, they're talking about the value of `L` after calling the function (which will always be `0` because that's what it was set to in the outer scope).

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a new value to `L` inside your function, you're actually creating a new variable that's independent of the `L` outside the function (which never changes and stays zero).  If you want to be able to access this value outside of the function, `return` it:

```
def confusionmatrix(target, prediction):
    L = 0
    dataframe=creatematrixnull(target)    
    for i in range(len(target)):
        dataframe[target[i]][prediction[i]]+=1
        L=L+1
    return dataframe, L

df, L = confusionmatrix(target, prediction)  # you need to actually call the function!
print(L)
```

However, you don't actually need to return `L` in this case, because it will always be the same as `len(target)`.  The easier way to write this function and get L afterward is:

```
def confusionmatrix(target, prediction):
    dataframe = creatematrixnull(target)    
    for t, p in zip(target, prediction):
        dataframe[t][p] += 1
    return dataframe

df = confusionmatrix(target, prediction)
L = len(target)
print(L)
```

Note that iterating over `t, p in zip(target, prediction)` gives you the same values as you'd get from `target[i]` and `prediction[i]` (as `t` and `p`) that you'd get by iterating over `i in range(len(target))`.